# Comprehension disconnect in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

*Novice Alert*

A mySQL table "tokens" contains a field, "dl" (DL), which is an integer (values: 0, 1 or 2)

For the row where field "token"==$stripped_token, the current value of "dl" is 0

I wish to read the record, increment the number found in field "DL" (zero) and update the record. Here's what I'm trying:

```
function sql_update_token($stripped_token)
{
    global $mysqli ;
    $curr_dl = $mysqli->query("SELECT dl FROM tokens WHERE token = ".$stripped_token) or die (mysqli_error());
    $new_num = $curr_dl + 1;
    $result = $mysqli->query("UPDATE tokens SET dl=".$new_num." WHERE token = ".$stripped_token) or die (mysqli_error());
}
```

The value of field DL is now "2" !  Why 2?

In troubleshooting the above, I tried this:

```
function sql_get_dl($stripped_token)
{
    global $mysqli ;
    $curr_dl_num = $mysqli->query("SELECT dl FROM tokens WHERE token = ".$stripped_token) or die (mysqli_error());
    return $curr_dl_num;
}


$test = sql_get_token($stripped_token);
echo('[$test] == [ '.$test.' ]<br />');
```

The problem is that $test does not contain the number "0", as I had hoped.  Instead, it contains: "current_field", "field_count", "lengths", "num_rows" and "type" (those text strings, in an array.

What are my errors?

Comment: Unless I'm misunderstanding,     $result = $mysqli->query("UPDATE tokens SET dl=dl+1 WHERE token = ".$stripped_token) or die (mysqli_error());
doesn't work for you?

Comment: What is your code for generating $stripped_token?

Comment: $stripped_token is generated by a function that strips "." and "|" from a string. It works correctly and is used in other functions to return the entire row. Those other functions work correctly. These functions are different in that they should only return the field value for "dl", and should UPDATE that value.  But $stripped_token has a correct value.

Comment: @Filgera -- You solved it, Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One problem is that msysqli->query doesn't return the value you think it returns. It returns a result object. You then need to get at the data in that result. i.e.:

```
global $mysqli ;
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT dl FROM tokens WHERE token = ".$stripped_token) or die (mysqli_error());
$row = $result->fetch_row();
$curr_dl_num = $row[0];
```

Think of $result as a table. fetch_row() gets the first row, and $row[0] gets the first cell of that row. This is really inconvenient, since you are only getting a table with one value in it, but with other queries, where multiple results are returned, being able to step through them using fetch_row() is really useful.

As well, how are you generating your $stripped_token value, since you said that wasn't behaving as you expected? If you are reading it from a mySQL query, your problem is probably the same - it might be a result object, and not a single value as you expect.

**EDIT:**
Never mind the bit about $stripped_token, I misinterpreted the last part of your question.

Comment: Thank you. As you realized, I was misunderstanding the format returned by $mysqli->query. fetch_row() is exactly what I needed to know. Gracias

Comment: @user674073 It's worth pointing out that, while this answer solves the problem, you could avoid the problem entirely by simply executing `UPDATE tokens SET dl = dl + 1 WHERE token = ...` instead of pulling a value from the database, incrementing it, and putting it back.

Comment: @djacobson That is true, assuming you never actually want to use the value. If you want to read the value and do something with it in a PHP script, then at some point you'll have to pull it out of a query like this.